# How to change the word into icon in Show/Hide in ReactJs

Tags: css, reactjs, web

Im having difficulty on making my show/hide as close and open eyes icon on showing password im still new to working with classNames in react, I hope you can help me

```
<span className="password__show" onClick={this.showHide}>
 {this.state.type === 'input' ? 
 "fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon " : "fa fa-fw fa-eye-slash field-icon "}
 </span>
```

Comment: See the [FontAwesome documentation](http://fontawesome.io/icon/eye/) on how to use the icons.

Comment: @fqhv thank you for suggestions but however how will i insert it in the condition...

Comment: [Chase DeAnda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44577036/5817001) should help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally fixed it.

```
render() {
        let show = (<i className="fa fa-eye"></i>);
        let hide = (<i className="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>);

return{
<span className="password__show" onClick={this.showHide}>
                    {this.state.type === 'input' ? hide:show}
                    </span>

}
```

Comment: inspired by the answer of Chase DeAnda

Answer (score 3):

You need to perform that logic in the `className` prop if you are trying to add the class to the span.

```
var icon_class = this.state.type === 'input' ? "fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon " : "fa fa-fw fa-eye-slash field-icon ";
<span className={"password__show " + icon_class} onClick={this.showHide}></span>
```

If you are doing a conditional render of the span contents then it would look like this:

```
var icon_class = this.state.type === 'input' ? "fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon " : "fa fa-fw fa-eye-slash field-icon ";
<span className="password__show" onClick={this.showHide}>
    <i className={icon_class} />
</span>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, I noticed that as soon as I posted it. I updated my answer, should work.

Comment: Ah okay sorry, I assumed you were using es6. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank you ive finally fixed it awhile ago my answer below was inspired from yours